# Is this class immutable?

Tags: java, immutability

Is this class immutable ?

I'm roughly trying to follow the guidelines in "Effective Java", "Item 15: Minimize mutability", hence the class is not "final" on purpose.

```
public class Result<T extends Number> {
    private final Map<String, T> result;

    private Result(final Map<String, T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public static final Result<? extends Number> of() {
        return new Result<>(new LinkedHashMap<>());
    }

    /** Add or replace value. */
    public Result<T> put(final String key, final T value) {
        result.put(key, value);
        return new Result<>(Collections.unmodifiableMap(result));
    }

    public T get(final String key) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result).get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think no, because you changed your `result` map with this line `result.put(key, value);`

Comment: No. The `put` method modifies it. If you want it to be immutable, you need to have only the new `Result` be different, not the original. As a side note, calling `put` on a `Result` returned by another `put` will throw an exception.

Comment: what would make you think it was immutable? What do you believe the definition of immutable is?

Comment: Have you tried using this class? It's not very usable without casting. The `of()` method returns a `Result<? extends Number>` but you'd not get around casting to be able to call any of the other methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `put` method should make a copy of the `Map`, then call `put` on the copy, and return a new `Result` constructed with the copied map.

```
/** Add or replace value. */
public Result<T> put(final String key, final T value) {
    Map<T> copy = new LinkedHashMap<>(result);
    copy.put(key, value);
    return new Result<>(copy);
}
```

Note that the implementation also relies on all subclasses of `Number` being immutable. Otherwise there is also an issue with the implementation of the `get` method.

```
public T get(final String key) {
    //Relies on T being immutable
    return result.get(key);
}
```

Comment: `Note that the implementation also relies on all subclasses of Number being immutable` or make deep copy

Comment: Thanks @AlekseiBulgak, added the note.